# Submitting HTML form with additional hidden data using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, google-app-engine

I'm trying to add another parameter using a hidden input:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){ //listen for submit event

        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', 'id')
            .attr('value', id)
            .appendTo('#form1');

    return true;

});
```

"id" is a global variable.

My HTML form:

```
 <form id="form1" method=POST runat="server" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="/set_image">
       <div class="fileButtons">
       <input type='file' id="imgInp" name="imgInp" accept="image/*"/>
        <input type='button' id='remove' name="remove" value='Remove' />
        </div>
     <br>


<div class="modal-footer">
        <a type="button" class="btn pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">OK</button>
      </div>    
    </form>
```

In the log console of Google app engine, I can see that only "id" gets its value.

In firebug, it shows while debugging:

```
imgInp
    input#imgInp property value = "2.jpg" attribute value = "null"
```

main.py:

```
class SetImage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        id = str(self.request.get('id'))
        image = str(self.request.get('impInp'))
        ...

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/set_image', SetImage),
                                ('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I used the post in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/993897/2653179

Edit: The problem was solved, it was a typo in the imgInp variable in SetImage class...

Comment: How do you know it does no do anything? what is `id` ?

Comment: I added the additional info in the first post.

Comment: try method=POST -> method="POST"

Comment: Tried it, still the same...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a typo in getting the image in SetImage class... :)

I wrote impInp instead of imgInp...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('name', 'id')
        .attr('value', id)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to get the id, but still not the image.

Comment: That is difficult to me.

Comment: I added more info... I appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Add the new field this way:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){ //listen for submit event

    $(this).append('<input name="' +id+ '" type="text" />');

});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQkKy/)**