# Rails add hidden param on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails 4.0 application and I am wondering is it possible to pass a hidden param with JS to a form on form submit in Rails?

Comment: Do you have any context?

Comment: I have some data which is changed during my clicks in the application. This JS library has e method that returns the data. So, the data is changed dynamically and I do not want to add/remove hidden param after some event. That's why I am wondering is it possible to call this JS method before submit, it should return the final content and then I can set it to hidden param.

Comment: You'll be able to do use the `.on("submit")` event in JS

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to actually apply it in the controller (not JS):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def create
   @model = Model.new(controller_params)
   @model.save
end

private

def controller_params
   params.require(:controller).permit(:params).merge(param: "value")
end
```

---

**Update**

In light of your comment, you'd be able to use the [`.on("submit")`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) function in JS like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "#form", function(){
    // append your params in here
});
```

As for adding the params, you could benefit from this:
[Adding POST parameters before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993834/adding-post-parameters-before-submit)

```
$('#commentForm').submit(function(){ //listen for submit event
    $.each(params, function(i,param){
        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', param.name)
            .attr('value', param.value)
            .appendTo('#commentForm');
    });

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a hidden field in your form that has a default value? With simple_form and haml it will look like this:

`= f.input :field, as: :hidden, default: :value`