# Can not read data from express form ( return null)

Tags: node.js, express

Can not read data from express form ( return null), I used the body parser in the server.js

```js
//Parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Here's the router method

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('customer');
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    console.log(req.body); 
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let customer = new Customer({
        name: req.body.name,
        mobile: req.body.mobile,
        isGold: req.body.isGold
    })
    console.log(customer);
    customer = await customer.save();

    res.send(customer);
});
```

Here's the html form , I have 3 fields ( name , mobile , isGold) :-

```html
 <form action="/api/customer" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
        <input type="mobile" class="form-control" 
        id="mobile" placeholder="Enter your Mobile">
      </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="isGold">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
          Is Gold
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: You do not need `body-parser`, the library in the newer versions of Express. replace with  `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded({ });`

Comment: Okay , But I got null before using the body parser.

Comment: You can also experiment by removing the `extended: true` flag. if this does not work, I have a feeling there is more to the code

Comment: I see that you don't binding data value to the http body, Can you try it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284362/5589964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **name property** to the input field.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
        <input type="mobile" class="form-control" 
        id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter your Mobile">
      </div>
</div>
```

Usually GET/POST request is sent in form of **key:value** pair.Here key is the name attribute of the form.

example : http://example.com/page?parameter=value&also=another

Here "parameter"(& "also")  is a form  input field name.

Comment: When I checked the checkbox , they gave this message '"isGold" must be a boolean' , how i can set it to boolean ?

Comment: better add a value field to the checkbox..
on server side you get a array of values on req.body.name-of-checkbox-field