# Add object(s) to form submission (post)

Tags: javascript, post

I have a form and I have two objects I want to submit with that form.

```
<form role="form" id="orderform" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <button type="submit">Place Order</button>
</form>

<script>

    var items1 = {name: "test", value: "123"} //needs to submit with form

    var items2 = {name: "test2", value: "456"} //meeds to submit with form

    $("#orderform").submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        //do something to add items1 and items2 to form.

    }

</script>
```

How do I submit `items1` and `items2` with the form submission?

Comment: Serialize them in some form (for example by encoding them as JSON), and put the results into hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

There are already answers to this question ([Adding POST parameters before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993834/adding-post-parameters-before-submit/993897)) but I personally think that adding dom elements should not be the way to go.

My approach would be to get the form data onsubmit and add your objects to it. Afterwards send the request. The major benefits are you can make use of ajax (which in fact improves the user experience) and dont have to modify / add dom elements which can get quite nasty if you add more than 2 objects.

```js
var items1 = {
  name: "test1",
  value: "123"
} //needs to submit with form

var items2 = {
  name: "test2",
  value: "456"
} //meeds to submit with form

$("#orderform").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  //add the items to the form data
  let data = $(this).serializeArray();
  data.push(items1);
  data.push(items2);
  let params = $.param(data);
  //send the data with ajax
  $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      window.location.href = "success.php"+params;
    },
    error: function() {
    }
});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="orderform" action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <button type="submit">Place Order</button>
</form>
```

In order to show the results on a seperate page I'd add the form data as get parameters to the success redirect and show them like this.

Please also read on XSS and how to avoid it (sanitize input / parameters).
success.php should look like the following.

```
echo $_GET["test1"];
echo $_GET["test2"];
```

Comment: Indeed this is a better answer.

Comment: Yes but how to I load a new page, like a confirmation page with the data?

Comment: Simply add window.location.href and then the desired url. @jac

Comment: With the data, meaning I need the confirmation page to show "items1", "items2"

Comment: Since I dont know your server structure (assuming you use php), my approach would be the following. Check my edited snippet. @jac

Comment: I don't understand how success.php is getting those two variables.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to add them to the url. Please check the snippet again  @jac

Answer (score 0):

You can add them as hidden inputs.

```js
let items = [
  {
    name: 'bar',
    value: 'foo',
  },
  {
    name: 'qux',
    value: 'baz',
  },
];

let form = document.getElementById('orderform');

let itemsToBeSubmited = items;
itemsToBeSubmited.forEach((item) => {
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  input.setAttribute('name', item.name);
  input.setAttribute('value', item.value);
  form.appendChild(input);
});
```

```html
<form role="form" id="orderform" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <button type="submit">Place Order</button>
</form>
```