# Add parameters while submitting a form in rails6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-6

Can I add additional parameters to the below submit function without adding hidden_fields in the form and ajax in rails6

```
$("#product_form").submit()
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993834/adding-post-parameters-before-submit/56149177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will append a hidden field with value just before submitting the form

```
 $("#product_form").append("`<input type='hidden' name='product_order' value='"+product_order+"' >`")
```

The hidden field will remain in the form if the form is not reloading during form submission